# Scoping rules in Lua

Tags: lua, scope

I was testing the scope for Lua and noticed something unexpected.  The following code does not print the localMainVariable.

```
function functionScope()
    print( "\nIn function")
    print( "globalMainVariable: " .. globalMainVariable )
    if (localMainVariable ~= nil) then print( "localMainVariable: " .. localMainVariable ) end
end

globalMainVariable = "Visible"
local localMainVariable = "Visible"
functionScope()
```

But the following code does print localMainVariable.

```
globalMainVariable = "Visible"
local localMainVariable = "Visible"

function functionScope()
    print( "\nIn function")
    print( "globalMainVariable: " .. globalMainVariable )
    if (localMainVariable ~= nil) then print( "localMainVariable: " .. localMainVariable )  end
end

functionScope()
```

I know it has something to do with where the localMainVariable was declared, but I thought making it local would limit the scope of the variable.  What is the actual rule?

Thanks

Comment: Just mentioning that, in the 2nd example, `localMainVariable` is called an **upvalue** for the `functionScope` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The scope of a local variable begins at the first statement after its
>   declaration and lasts until the last non-void statement of the
>   innermost block that includes the declaration.

[Lua manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.5)